# Use .innerHTML to define a input field with ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, camunda

I want to create multiple input fields in a for-loop and assign a unique `ng-model` name to each field so I can use the values later.
Here is how I did it. `inputmap` is a map.

```
<script cam-script type="text/form-script">
for (let i=0;i<3;i++){
   var name = "inputmap.item"+ i.toString(); // inputmap.item0, inputmap.item1, inputmap.item2, etc
   document.getElementById("inputs").innerHTML += "<input type='text' ng-model='" + name + "' required/><br>" 
}
</script>

<div id="inputs"></div>
```

But when I look at the `$scope.inputmap`, it's empty.

When I hardcode the input fields like:

```
<div id="inputs">
   <input type='text' ng-model='inputmap.item0' required/><br>
   <input type='text' ng-model='inputmap.item1' required/><br>
   <input type='text' ng-model='inputmap.item2' required/><br>
</div>
```

I was able to get the values I entered in the fields. I am new to HTML and any help/hints is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First you have `+=` on `document.getElementById("inputs").innerHTML += "<input type='text' ng-model='" + name + "' required/><br>"` and can be changed to just `=`

There are to ways to do this. I think if you change `document.getElementById("inputs").innerHTML += "<input type='text' ng-model='" + name + "' required/><br>"` to `` document.getElementById("inputs").innerHTML = `<input type='text' ng-model="${name}" required/><br>` ``  then that will add it in correctly. Never done this though and might not work where you can do my second way of doing it:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   let input = document.createElement('input') //Creates input element
   let wrapper = document.getElementById('inputs') //Gets the div element 
   let name = `inputmap.item${i.toString()}` //Gets the name

   input.setAttribute('ng-model', name) // Sets 'ng-model' attribute to name
   wrapper.appendChild(input) //Sets 'wrapper' as 'input' parent 
}
```

Hope this helps!